# HTML/CSS Table, how do I increase width of table without affecting width of cells?

Tags: css, width, cell, html-table

I have a table whose width is 80% of screensize. This table contains my menu items. Menu items are in the form of table cells. The design I want is that each cell should only be as wide as the text inside it. But I also want a last cell, that will be empty and be as wide as the remaining space in the table. I.E I want the last to inherit the width of the table (remaining space).

But, all the cells get stretched when I increase table width instead of them just fitting to their text.

How do I stop this from happening?

1. I want all but last of the cells to exactly fit their text.
2. I want the last cell to take up all the remaining space.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried inserting another element inside the last td? like a input or span.

Comment: Is it possible to specify fixed width on "text" cells?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly That one is not answered. I am using HTML5 so I can't use nowrap.

Comment: @Passerby no, I don't want to do that. I want it to fit whatever the content of the text cells maybe.

Comment: @PrashanthSubramanianIyer: Use CSS. `td { white-space:nowrap; }` `td:last-child { white-space:normal; }`

Comment: Ark, no I have not. Could you please elaborate, I am new to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend the last cell to occupy full width:

```
td:last-child {
    width: 100%;
}
```

…and, if you want to make sure the text in the other cells doesn't collapse:

```
td {
    whitespace: nowrap;
}
```

Demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/barney/kz77m/

Comment: It'll work some kind of better, too ;) — `table-cell` display properties (height stretched to fit, vertical alignment, etc) are quite unique, so setting the last cell to display `inline` has plenty of nasty side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple via CSS. You just modify the `display` style to `inline`.

Attached fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CZYSa/

Comment: I tried the same, but it stretches the first to last but one cells to fill the table width..

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand the comment, does the fiddle linked above not work?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Your solution works great.

I have one additional question though. If I have a <td>reallylongword space_reallylongWord</td>
, the layout goes for a toss (the height of the tr increases), how do I stop that?

Thanks!

Comment: please check with http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp if this is helpful

Comment: Thanks a lot hexblot. I had to do a white-space:nowrap; which I found out after studying work-break. Thanks again :)